# How to use exists keyword in insert statment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following insert query need to be executed.

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE NAME (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4)
  VALUES (**(select COLID1 from ATABLE1 where ATABLE1.COLID2 = VALUE and ATABLE1.COLID3 = 
  (select COLID3 from BTABLE1 where BTABLE1.ColdID = VALUE)**),VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4)
```

To insert the above statement should follow below condition

- A query which is highlighted in the insert statement. The insert
  statement will be executed only if the highlighted query returns a
  value otherwise it shouldn't be executed.
- I know we have Keyword 'exists' in sqlserver. but where I want to put
  that keyword I don't know. Can anyone please.

Comment: COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4 these four columns will from how many tables please mention those tables

Comment: Use 'yourKeyword'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSERT`/`SELECT` instead:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE NAME (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4)
select COLID1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4
from ATABLE1 where ATABLE1.COLID2 = VALUE and ATABLE1.COLID3 = 
  (select COLID3 from BTABLE1 where BTABLE1.ColdID = VALUE)
```

If the `select` returns no rows, no rows will be inserted.

Comment: Why ur passing VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4 in the select statement. That is 3 not depend upon subquery. It's independent values

Comment: @Vinay - because the contents of the `SELECT` clause are *what are being inserted into the corresponding columns identified by the `INSERT`*. That's where you put *anything* that's going into the table.